# Is the current spate of hacks related to the recent security fix?

Tags: hacked

There has been a rash of hacks over the last week.  In each case the content of the post has been edited with either an infantile "hacked by" or a political message.

This post https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.7.2 refers to versions 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 being affected by *an Unauthenticated Privilege Escalation Vulnerability in a REST API Endpoint*

Are the vandals taking advantage of this vulnerability in out of date WP installs or is this a different issue?

I want to know if upgrading to 4.7.2 is the solution - yeah I know people should use the most recent version, but they aren't my sites.

Comment: https://wptavern.com/wordpress-rest-api-vulnerability-is-being-actively-exploited-hundreds-of-thousands-of-sites-defaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Sucuri, [there are some defacement campaigns underway](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/02/wordpress-rest-api-vulnerability-abused-in-defacement-campaigns.html). Also, it appears that there are [attempts at remote code execution](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/02/rce-attempts-against-the-latest-wordpress-rest-api-vulnerability.html). So yes: **if you're running 4.7 or 4.7.1, upgrade to 4.7.2 as soon as possible.**

Comment: Thanks...yes I suspected 4.7.2 was the solution, but wanted to be certain.  One defacement included the person's email address so I contacted him (using a disposable email) and he said "Primision i access" which even allowing for bad English was a good clue.